# Bypass Zookeeper in producer/consumer clients?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

This is a follow-up question to an [earlier discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534398/when-does-kafka-connection-require-zookeeper-config).  I think of Zookeeper as a coordinator for instances of the Kafka broker, or "message bus".  I understand why we might want producer/consumer clients transacting through Zookeeper -- because Zookeeper has built-in fault-tolerance as to which Kafka broker to transact with.  But with the new model -- ie, 0.10.1+ -- should we always bypass Zookeeper altogether in our producer/consumer clients?  Are we giving up any advantages (Eg, better fault-tolerance) by doing that?  Or is Zookeeper ultimately still at work behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zookeeper is still at work behind the scenes but the 0.9+ clients don't need to worry about it anymore because consumer offsets are now stored in a Kafka topic rather than in zookeeper.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer of Hans Jespersen, recent Kafka producer/consumer clients (0.9+) do not interact with ZooKeeper anymore.

Nowadays ZooKeeper is only used by the Kafka brokers (i.e., the server-side of Kafka).  This means you can e.g. lock-down external access from clients to all ZooKeeper instances for better security.

> I understand why we might want producer/consumer clients transacting through Zookeeper -- because Zookeeper has built-in fault-tolerance as to which Kafka broker to transact with.

Producer/consumer clients are not "transacting" through ZooKeeper, see above.

> But with the new model -- ie, 0.10.1+ -- should we always bypass Zookeeper altogether in our producer/consumer clients?

If the motivation of your question is because you want to implement your own Kafka producer or consumer client, then the answer is:  your custom client should not ZooKeeper any longer.  The official Kafka producer/consumer clients (Java/Scala) or e.g. [Confluent's C/C++, Python, or Go clients for Kafka](http://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/index.html) demonstrate how scalability, fault-tolerance, etc. can be achieved by leveraging Kafka functionality (rather than having to rely on a separate service such as ZooKeeper).

> Are we giving up any advantages (Eg, better fault-tolerance) by doing that? Or is Zookeeper ultimately still at work behind the scenes?

No, we are not giving up any advantages here.  Otherwise the Kafka project would not have changed its producer/consumer clients to stop using ZooKeeper and start using Kafka themselves for their inner workings.

ZooKeeper is only still at work behind the scenes for the Kafka *brokers*, see above.